# Convergence in distribution and $L^1$-convergence of $f(X_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ and $X$ be independent random variables. If $X_n \to X$ weakly, then $E|f(X_n)-f(X)|\to 0$ for continuous bounded function $f$ ?

Because of convergence in distribution, there exist $Y_n,Y$ s.t.,$Y_n\to Y$ a.s., $X_n=Y_n$ and $X=Y$ in distribution. So, by Lebesgue's theorem $E|f(Y_n)-f(Y)|\to 0$.

But I don't know whether it holds that $E|f(X_n)-f(X)|=E|f(Y_n)-f(Y)|$.

Some one prove this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d with standard normal distribution. Then $X_n \to X_1$ weakly and $-X_n \to X_1$ weakly (by symmetry of the distribution). If the result is true then $E|sin (X_n)-\sin (X_1)| \to 0$ and $E|-sin (X_n)-\sin (X_1)| \to 0$. By triangle inequality this gives $2 E|sin (X_n)| \to 0$. But $ E|sin (X_n)|= E|sin (X_1)|>0$.